# Connection keep alive for AWS Glue

Tags: python, oracle, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

We are trying to insert huge dataset of records in onprem Oracle database approx 2 million records,but we get this error message during execution

```
2022-06-15 03:53:43,095 ERROR [main] glue.ProcessLauncher (Logging.scala:logError(70)): Error from Python:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/reverse_sync_bdnsar_history_tables", line 283, in <module>
    glueContext.write_from_options(frame_or_dfc=detailHistoryMapping, connection_type="oracle",connection_options=connection_oracle18_options_source)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/context.py", line 352, in write_from_options
    return sink.write(frame_or_dfc)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 35, in write
    return self.writeFrame(dynamic_frame_or_dfc, info)
  File "/opt/amazon/lib/python3.6/site-packages/awsglue/data_sink.py", line 31, in writeFrame
    return DynamicFrame(self._jsink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(dynamic_frame._jdf, callsite(), info), dynamic_frame.glue_ctx, dynamic_frame.name + "_errors")
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/amazon/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o318.pyWriteDynamicFrame.
: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:770)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.close(PhysicalConnection.java:4585)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.glue.GlueJDBCSink$.save(GlueJDBCSink.scala:43)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.util.JDBCWrapper.writeDF(JDBCUtils.scala:892)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.sinks.OracleDataSink.writeDynamicFrame(OracleDataSink.scala:20)
    at com.amazonaws.services.glue.DataSink.pyWriteDynamicFrame(DataSink.scala:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:426)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:390)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:249)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOLOGOFF(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:59)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logoff(T4CConnection.java:757)
    ... 16 more
```

We analysed the issue and found out that if if we can keep the connection alive the firewall wont think this is a stale connection. We did similar configurations for cx_oracle and it worked. Unfortunately we dont know such configuration in AWS Glue. Currently we are partitioning dataframe and inserting data in smaller chunks like 50k but this takes alot of time.

If there are any other solution than keeping Connection alive that would also be fine

Comment: Can you just use cx_Oracle, or rather, the new version of cx_Oracle which doesn't need Oracle Instant Client? See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  Use `executeMany()` of course, see [Executing Batch Statement and Bulk Loading](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html).

Comment: @ChristopherJones: we want a solution for aws glue to use its batch capability. If we use cx_oracle then i need to create a framework for parallel processing among multiple workers. AWS Glue uses odbc .jar to connect oracle db